# Can't make my DB search results appear using Ajax and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I can see the correct results using console.log but when I try to display the results in the span I created below my search box nothing appears.

HTML:

```
<form method="GET" action="recherche.php" class="form ml-auto" autocomplete="off">
    <input id="search" name="search" class="form-control mb-1" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    //This is where I want the results displayed
    <span class="search-results"></span>
    <button value="Soumettre" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Rechercher</button>
  </form>
```

CSS:

```
.search-results{
display:block;
position:absolute;
background-color:#fff;
border:1px solid black;
padding:10px 20px;
z-index:10;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var valueText = document.getElementById('search');
var resultsSpan = document.getElementsByClassName('search-results');
var form = document.querySelector('search');
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
valueText.addEventListener('keyup' , function(){
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(xhr.readyState == 4){
        if(xhr.status == 200){
            var resultat = [];
          resultsSpan.className + 'search-results'
          console.log('this.responseText', this.responseText)
          console.log('resultsSpan', resultsSpan)
          var results = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
          for (let i=0; i<results.length; i++){
              resultat.push('<li>' + results[i].titre + '</li>');
          }
          resultsSpan.innerHTML = resultat;
        }else{
            console.log('Error' , xhr.statusText)
        }
    }
}
xhr.open("GET", "search.php?search=" + valueText.value, true);
xhr.send(null);
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try `resultsspan[0].innerHTML`? Keep in mind `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks Chipster! Apologies for the duplicate question.